# jQuery .click() activates addClass() & class uses transform: translate to move element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I am making an image slider with two arrows on either side of the slider. For instance, when `.click()` the `.rightArrow`, a class is added ( `.addClass()` ) called `.moveRight`.

```
.moveRight{
    transform: translate(760px,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(760px,0); /** Safari & Chrome **/
    -o-transform: translate(760px,0); /** Opera **/
    -moz-transform: translate(760px,0); /** Firefox **/
}
```

The **problem** is that this click event *only triggers once*. I imagine this is because I am telling the moveable element to go to a specific location.

I want to the element to keep moving right for a certain amount of px every time I `.click()` the `.rightArrow`.

The jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.rightArrow').click( function() {
    $('.imgGluedToThis').removeClass("moveLeft");
    $('.imgGluedToThis').addClass("moveRight");
  });
  $('.leftArrow').click( function() {
    $('.imgGluedToThis').removeClass("moveRight");
    $('.imgGluedToThis').addClass("moveLeft");
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
      <img src="rightArrow.png" class="rightArrow">
      <img src="leftArrow.png" class="leftArrow">
      <div class="pictures-container">
        <div class="imgGluedToThis">
          <div class="picture-container">
            <a href="#openModal1">
           <img src="house.png" class="picture">
          </a>
          </div>
          <div class="picture-container">
            <a href="#openModal1">
            <img src="building.png" class="picture">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="picture-container">
            <a href="#openModal1"> 
            <img src="house2.png" class="picture">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="picture-container">
            <a href="#openModal1">
           <img src="house.png" class="picture">
          </a>
          </div>
          <div class="picture-container">
            <a href="#openModal1">
            <img src="building.png" class="picture">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="picture-container">
            <a href="#openModal1"> 
            <img src="house2.png" class="picture">
            </a>
          </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rightArrow').click( function() {
     $('.imgGluedToThis').css('left','+=10px');
  });
  $('.leftArrow').click( function() {
     $('.imgGluedToThis').css('left','-=10px');
  });
});
```

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/943zb/2/)</kbd>

Or use **[`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rightArrow').click( function() {
      $('.imgGluedToThis').animate({'left':'+=10px'});
  });
  $('.leftArrow').click( function() {
      $('.imgGluedToThis').animate({'left':'-=10px'});
  });
});
```

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/943zb/4/)</kbd>

Comment: Both of these work. My imGluedToThis class was also not position relative. Thanks Pranav!

Answer (score 2):

The click event is triggering correctly every time - translate will move an element to a specific position. If it is already 760px across and click is called again to move it to 760px, nothing appears to happen.

You could set up a few classes to define where the leftmost, rightmost etc images should display, updating the classes for each element accordingly.

If the slider needs to be infinite, you will need to update the DOM too to set the elements to the correct order, updating the classes again once you have done so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use translate, specifically, you will need to track it and change it with code, perhaps like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // closures
    var iImageIndex = 0;
    var iSlideWidth = 760;
    var iImageMax = $('.picture-container').size();
    var $slides = $('.imgGluedToThis');
    var fTranslate = function (iDirection) {
        iDirection = (iDirection && (iDirection < 0) ) ? -1 : 1;        // normalize direction
        iImageIndex = iImageIndex + iDirection;                         // increment direction
        iImageIndex = iImageIndex < 0 ? iImageMax + iImageMax : iImageIndex; // check left end
        iImageIndex = iImageIndex % iImageMax;                          // check right end
        $slides.css('transform', 'translate(' + (iSlideWidth * iImageIndex) + 'px, 0)');
    }
    // event methods (closures)
    var fClickLeft = function () {
        fTranslate(-1);
    };
    var fClickRight = function () {
        fTranslate(1);
    };
    // event handlers
    $('.rightArrow').click(fClickRight);
    $('.leftArrow').click(fClickLeft);
});
```